# Remove negative results from SUM

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following code below to group and sum stock for my inventory. For some of my stock I can get negative results if there are more shipments than inventory, but I would like for these negative quantity items not to show in the "stock page" I have. Is there a way to remove the rows that are equal or less than 0 for quantity?

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ProductID   |  Color  | Timestamp          |  Quantity  |  RowID  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
25          |  Red    | 10/10/10 06:22:15  |  -250      |  1      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
32          |  Green  | 10/10/10 06:23:45  |  100       |  2      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------

$query = "SELECT productid, color, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity FROM inventory GROUP BY productid, color";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

   // Table markup here
   echo '<tr><td>'. $row['productid'] . '</td><td>' . $row['color']. '</td><td>'. $row['TotalQuantity'];
   // Table markup here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query = "Select * from 
  (SELECT productid, color, 
   SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity FROM inventory 
   GROUP BY productid, color) AS alias 
where TotalQuantity  > 0";
```

Comment: Hey thanks for helping, this looks like it should work - but I am getting an error "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: `$query = "Select * from 
  (SELECT productid, color, 
   SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity FROM inventory 
   GROUP BY productid, color) AS alias
where TotalQuantity  > 0";`